# Populating multiple values in rdlc reporting

Tags: reporting-services

I am using rdlc report, i have a column in database which i want to display in the report.

```
vehicleDamageArea=1,2,3
```

In the report I need to mark the placeholders with these values.

`=iif((Fields!vehicleDamageArea.Value="3"),Chr(253),Chr(168))` like this.

But as we know,it will check the whole value 1,2,3="3" not the splitted values. 
Any suggestion to check by splitting the vehicleDamageArea parameter.

I made  it to work as below

```
 Public Shared Function CheckValue(ByVal InString As String,ByVal input as String) As Char
 Dim output As String = String.Empty
        Dim Parts() As String = InString.ToString().Split(",")
        For i As Integer = 0 To Parts.Length - 1
            If Parts(i) = input Then
                output = Chr(0120)
                Exit For
            Else
                output = Chr(0111)                
            End If
        Next i
        Return output
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the individual values using the split function in reporting services. It returns a zero-based string array, so for your example you need

```
=Split(First(Fields!ID.Value),",")(2)
```

Comment: i tried the above expression , (2) giving me the synatax error

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion .BTW hw to accept someone's answer.I didn't see any link to do the same

Answer (score 0):

You should make a function that accept a comma separated expression, than process this string  and return a Boolean, then call this function as for boolean value.